# How to create generic constraint based on dependent type?

Tags: scala, slick, dependent-type

I have the following classes

```
trait Identifiable 


case class Address extends Identifiable


abstract class AbstractTable[T] {
  type TableElementType
}


class TableQuery[E <: AbstractTable[_]]


class Addresses(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "addresses")
```

How to make the

```
abstract class AbstractOptionBaseRepsitory[T <: AbstractTable[_]]
```

accept only `T` where `T#TableElementType` is a subclass of `Identifiable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 abstract class IdentifiableAbstractTable[T] extends AbstractTable[T] {
    type TableElementType <: Identifiable
 }

 abstract class AbstractOptionBaseRepository[T <: IdentifiableAbstractTable[_]]
```